# HttpContext is null when trying to unit test a Controller with webgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test a controller with a webgrid as such

```
var grid = new WebGrid(ajaxUpdateContainerId: "container-grid",ajaxUpdateCallback: "setArrows",  canSort: true);
```

I always get this error

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: httpContext
```

Here's my Test method

```
    var mockContext = CreateMockContext();
    UserController target = new UserController();
    target.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();
    target.ControllerContext.HttpContext = mockContext.Http.Object;
    Nullable<int> page = new Nullable<int>();
    string sort = "CreatedDate";
    string sortdir = "ASC";
    ActionResult actual;
    actual = target.Payments(page, sort, sortdir);
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
```

Here's my CreateMockContext method

```
public UnitTestBase CreateMockContext()
        {
            this.RoutingRequestContext = new Mock<RequestContext>(MockBehavior.Loose);
            this.ActionExecuting = new Mock<ActionExecutingContext>(MockBehavior.Loose);
            this.Http = new Mock<HttpContextBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);
            this.Server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);
            this.Response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);
            this.Request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);
            this.Session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);
            this.Cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();

            this.RoutingRequestContext.SetupGet(c => c.HttpContext).Returns(this.Http.Object);
            this.ActionExecuting.SetupGet(c => c.HttpContext).Returns(this.Http.Object);
            this.Http.SetupGet(c => c.Request).Returns(this.Request.Object);
            this.Http.SetupGet(c => c.Response).Returns(this.Response.Object);
            this.Http.SetupGet(c => c.Server).Returns(this.Server.Object);
            this.Http.SetupGet(c => c.Session).Returns(this.Session.Object);
            this.Http.SetupGet(p => p.User.Identity.Name).Returns("admin");
            this.Http.SetupGet(p => p.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
            this.Request.Setup(c => c.Cookies).Returns(Cookies);
            return this;
        }
```

I can test other controller just fine. Only controllers with webgrid fail.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're instantiating `WebGrid` in the controller? It seems based on [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx) that you could move the `WebGrid` instantiation into the view for the controller and remove that dependency from it's logic. That would certainly make writing the unit test much easier.

Comment: I was doing server-side paging and need to pass a _db.Count() as rowCount, and I didn't want to pass it through ViewBag.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `WebGrid` but a better approach may be to use a [strongly typed view](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views) to pass the counts. It seems to me that managing the grid element is a concern that belongs to the view and not a controller responsibility. That way the controllers remains focused on interacting with the model and passing the appropriate data to the view. Just my 2 bits :)

Comment: I have the same problem here, but in my case I'm instantiating the WebGrid in my ViewModel.  Would be nice to be able to unit test that part of my model but looks like it isn't possible.